# How to get row data in the order columns are arranged?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the following code to get the details of a particular row.

> var data = cell.getRow().getData();

But the results are not in the order of the column arrangement.

How to get the row's data with the column order maintained?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any function to retrieve the data in the defined order directly but you can use the below lines of code as a workaround:

```
var colsOrder = []; // The ordered columns
cell.getRow().getTable().getColumns().forEach(function(rec){
    colsOrder.push(rec.getField());
});

var val = []; // The ordered values
colsOrder.forEach(function(r){
    val.push(cell.getRow().getData()[r]);
});
```

I hope this will help !